# Disable automatic go to first row of Datagridview when click specific row

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with tons of data, but my problem is that when i select at row 600 after doing something like change font/backcolor the DataGridView scroll on top. how to disable it or work around ?

Comment: Capture the row index upon each rowchange, and re set the position after each refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can control which row is first selected by setting the [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx).